# spark add a col to dataframe with condtions on another df

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have the following problem: I want to add a column `RealCity` to dataframe A, when City value is 'noClue', I what to select from df B, using the Key, to get the City.

Table A:

```
   +---------+--------+
   |     Key |    City|   
   +---------+--------+
   |a        |    PDX |   
   +---------+--------+
   |b        | noClue |
```

Table B:

```
   +---------+--------+
   |     Key |  Name  |   
   +---------+--------+
   |c        |    SYD |   
   +---------+--------+
   |b        |   AKL  |
```

I want to use `.withColumn`and `when` but I can't select value another table (table B) by doing it this way.  What's a good way of doing this? Many Thanks!

Comment: how big is your Table B

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that you have two `dataframes`

A:

```
+---+------+
|key|City  |
+---+------+
|a  |PDX   |
|b  |noClue|
+---+------+
```

B:

```
+---+----+
|key|Name|
+---+----+
|a  |SYD |
|b  |AKL |
+---+----+
```

You can simply `join` them with common `Key` and use `withColumn` and `when` function as

```
val finalDF = A.join(B, Seq("Key"), "left").withColumn("RealCity", when($"City" === "noClue", $"Name").otherwise($"City")).drop("Name")
```

you should have final output as

```
+---+------+--------+
|key|City  |RealCity|
+---+------+--------+
|a  |PDX   |PDX     |
|b  |noClue|AKL     |
+---+------+--------+
```